# How to dynamically compare same period based on a slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to compare the same period of sessions per day. If i'm looking at Oct 10th 2018 to Oct. 16th 2018 (Wednesday to Tuesday), I would like to compare it to the same day range of last week:

```
+------+-------+-----+----------+-------------+--+
| year | month | day | sessions | last_period |  |
+------+-------+-----+----------+-------------+--+
| 2018 | oct   |  10 |     2000 |        2500 |  |
| 2018 | oct   |  11 |     2500 |        2400 |  |
| 2018 | oct   |  12 |     2600 |        2300 |  |
| 2018 | oct   |  13 |     2700 |        2450 |  |
| 2018 | oct   |  14 |     2400 |        2500 |  |
| 2018 | oct   |  15 |     2300 |        2200 |  |
| 2018 | oct   |  16 |     2000 |        1150 |  |
+------+-------+-----+----------+-------------+--+
```

A simple formula can make it work based on the 7-day interval:

```
same_last_period = CALCULATE(SUM(table[Sessions]),DATEADD(table[Date],-7,DAY))
```

but I would like the formula to depend on a date slicer. Say if i wanted to look at the Oct 1-Oct 20. I would like my formula to change and look at the same period right before with the same amount of day intervals. Ultimately this would be graphed as well.

Comment: Can you simply change `-7` to a count of the selected days? Something like `COUNTROWS(VALUES(table[Date]))` or `DISTINCTCOUNT(ALLSELECTED(table[Date]))`?

Comment: it gives the last day's value (using the COUNTROWS function)
DISTINCTCOUNT doesn't work as it only takes a column reference as an argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
same_last_period =
VAR DayCount = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(table[Date]), ALLSELECTED(table[Date]))
RETURN CALCULATE(SUM(table[Sessions]), DATEADD(table[Date], -DayCount, DAY))
```

---

**Edit:**

This above doesn't work how I intended since you still have the year, month, and day in your filter context. That needs to be removed.

```
same_last_period =
VAR DayCount =
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'table'[Date] ),
        ALLSELECTED ( 'table'[Date] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'table', 'table'[Date] )
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'table'[Sessions] ),
        DATEADD ( 'table'[Date], -DayCount, DAY ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'table', 'table'[Date] )
    )
```

The `ALLEXCEPT` removes any extra filter context except for `Date`.

[image: Result]

Comment: Unfortunately the distinctcount function only accepts a column as an argument

Comment: still gives me yesterday's amount

Comment: I got it working by adjusting the filter context a bit more.

Comment: it gives me a blank column

Comment: It works on my computer. You must have some tables or relationships that you have not specified.